# Is it design pattern: create object with identifier or return if already exists?

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop, design-patterns

main principles:

- `object` could be created through `class method` by providing unique identifier (whatever)
- if `object` with given identifier doesn't exists, returned new `object` otherwise returned existing one
- `class` guarantees that ONLY ONE `object` with given identifier could exist (sort of internal `singleton`)

So main point in keeping `objects` with unique filed (f.e id) for future using, since they might have own states (f.e loading, loaded so on) we are allowed to use it everywhere we need it without re-creating.

Is it `design pattern`?

F.e:

**Advirtisement.h**

```
@interface Advertisment : NSObject

+ (instancetype)adWithID:(NSString *)adID;    
+ (NSMutableArray *)sharedAds;
```

**Advertisement.m**

```
+ (instancetype)adWithID:(NSString *)adID {

    NSMutableArray *ads = [[self class] sharedAds];
        // Look for existing ad based on the id
        Advertisement *returnableAd = nil;
        for (Advertisement *currentAd in ads) {
            if ([currentAd.adID isEqualToString:adID]) {
                returnableAd = currentAd;
                break;
            }
        }
        // Create a new ad instance for this id if one doesn't already exist.
        if (!returnableAd) {
            returnableAd = [[[self class] alloc] initWithID:adID];                                                                  
            [ads addObject:returnableAd];
        }
        return returnableAd;
    }
}

+ (NSMutableArray *)sharedAds
{
    static NSMutableArray *sharedAds;

    if (!sharedAds) {
        sharedAds = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    return sharedAds;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's [Lazy Initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization) - and some would also consider it an instance of a [Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)) (others would argue that in itself a factory doesn't constitute a pattern)